# Can my son get a Netherlands visa

Tags: visa, netherlands

My son is on a two year student visa in UK and would like to stay longer. Both my parents are dutch. My mum is not naturalised but my father is. My mother moved to NZ in 1955 and dad came over at about 1950.  I was born in NZ in 1965.  So my question is: Can my son get a dutch year visa either through his grand parents or even through me having dutch parents. My son is also born in NZ 1992.

Comment: I'm not aware of a special visa for people with Dutch heritage, but I will have a look later when I have some more time.  There's a small chance that your son is actually a Dutch citizen, though, depending on when your father naturalized.  If he naturalized after you were born (or separately from his parents and before he turned 21), then you were probably Dutch when you were born, and I believe you would still have been Dutch when your son was born, and since he is not yet 28, he would not have lost his Dutch nationality.

Comment: @phoog If the father naturalized before the OP was born, then the OP probably qualifies for the easy version of the Option Procedure and so does her son.

Comment: @Eric yes of course.  Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Hi Emma. I am nitpicking here - when you say your son wants to stay longer, do you refer to staying in the UK or Netherlands? The reason I am asking so is because a dutch visa is likely not able to grant automatic entry to the UK, if that (in the most unlikely case) is what you are looking for...